# is it ok to use a global reference for the components that are supposed to be at most 1 in the document for setting its properties?

Tags: lit

It's hard to get data between components if they have a bit complex
structure. Yes there's a plenty of state management libraries out there.
But I wonder what if all I need to do is just to set a different value for a
component that I can't reach from where I want to set it.

for example, I have a tabs component (there will be only 1).
I also added a button that sets a different tab but I can't reach `my-tabs` from it.

so can't I just

```js
class MyTabs extends LitElement {
    static properties = {
        active: {}
    }
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.active = 0
        window.tabs = this
    }
}

class MyButton extends LitElement {
    render(){
        return html`
            <button @click=${e => window.tabs.active = 2}>back to tab 2</button>
        `
    }
}
```

It has a rule tho - **1 instance at most** && **you can't get. only to set** cuz:

- when used get:
  you get the actual value but when an update occurs for `my-tabs` it won't
  update `my-button` leaving old data in display.
- when used set:
  the new value will be considered in `my-tabs` and rendered accordingly.
  nothing affected.

*now I think about array of components being stored in a global array with
onconnect/disconnected callbacks)*

I know it's a big no-no for reusability but I build my project using lit and
never plan to publish the components. most of them are already very specific for
the project. so yeah, I know it's bad for reusability but what if I don't care
about it. can it give some other side effects? or is it simply ok to? what about
the array one? thanks in advance <3

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using events instead.

If `MyButton` is a child of `MyTabs`, you can have `MyButton` dispatch it from itself with bubble and compose, and have `MyTabs` listen for it.

If they are siblings, then you may need to do it on some common parent, or `window`.

```js
class MyButton extends LitElement {
    dispatchTabChange(tabIndex) {
      const event = new CustomEvent('tab-change', {detail: tabIndex});
      window.dispatch(event);
    }

    render() {
        return html`
            <button @click=${() => dispatchTabChange(2)}>back to tab 2</button>
        `
    }
}

class MyTabs extends LitElement {
    static properties = {
        active: {}
    }
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.active = 0
    }
    tabChangeListener(e) {
        this.active = e.detail;
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        window.addEventListener('tab-change', this.tabChangeListener);
    }
    disconnectedCallback() {
        window.removeEventListener('tab-change', this.tabChangeListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: oh this makes so much more sense than my "no get only set" rule since it's already not possible and seeing `tab-change` as a global event rather than a "setting property of a promised to be single component" is more comforting and semantically better. thanks I think this was the answer I wanted to get.

Answer (score 0):

It is your code, you can add as many globals, pigeons or telegraph poles to your code as you want.

Your HTML probably looks something like:

```html
<my-tabs>
 shadowroot
  <my-tab id="tab1"></my-tab>
    shadowroot
      <button></button>
  <my-tab id="tab2"></my-tab>
    shadowroot
      <button></button>      
  <my-tab id="tab3"></my-tab>
    shadowroot
      <button></button>
</my-tabs>
```

"problem" with Lit is, by default it sticks a shadowDOM on every element.

That means you can't use the default `.closest("my-tabs")` to *walk up* the DOM

You *can* add a `closestElement("my-tabs")` method that **crosses shadowroot boundaries** issued from your `<button>`

```js
  closestElement(selector, el = this) {
    return (
      (el && el != document && el != window && el.closest(selector)) ||
      this.closestElement(selector, el.getRootNode().host)
    );
  }
```

It might be easier to only keep ONE shadowDOM on `<my-tabs>` and non on `<my-tab>`; makes `closest()` work and styling a whole lot easier

Comment: appreciate the effort. my tabs element is kinda similar to your snippet but there's one more button which is not a child of tabs. also this makes a query. so isn't setting a global reference at constructor better for that?

Comment: Its your call, there is no "better" in programming.

Comment: there is. but I wasn't clear, I meant "optimal" - if I can reach that reference without a query, then it's an unnecessary step that hits (even if it's small) performance

Comment: You should also replace all ``let`` and ``const`` with ``var`` then... its faster. And replace all functional programming with ``for`` loops.

Comment: welp, there's a lot of things to consider if we're talking about `var`, `let` or other stuff that are the base of the programming language which can be used for anything that we can't even think of. but for a this specific case, the speed is the only parameter that I could think of **and** I asked if there's other things to consider. that's the whole point of my question. I'm sorry if I annoyed you with this little performance complain. just wanted to look from different angles. thanks again